# Network profile inbox page count is off by 1 if last page has exactly 20 items

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, stackexchange.com, pagination

In [my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/201110/shadow-wizard) inbox I have lots of items. Wanted to see the first items I got so clicked the last page:

> [image]

Just to be greeted with cryptic and misleading "No inbox items":

> [image]

I don't want to click "next" 522 times. Can this please be fixed?

On further investigation using the direct URLs (which are normally loaded via AJAX) I found the last page is actually 521 and it contains exactly 20 items.

**Edit**: now that I got more items, I can indeed see the last page so the previous assumption is proved: page count is incorrect if last page has 20 items exactly.

Comment: No repro here. I can go to the last page easily (by clicking on the last page number).

Comment: @hims056 just wait until the last page will have 20 items (i.e. (total items % 20 == 0) ;)

Comment: @hims056 I can help you with that, how much more you need? (Will post comments on posts of yours then delete after you confirm it's happening)

Comment: 5 more to go...

Comment: Stupid rate limit... please be patient

Comment: It seems the global inbox is cached as well.

Comment: @hims056 done! 5 items should be added, cache or no cache :)

Comment: [Reproduced now...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qUaYW.png)

Comment: @hims056 finally! ;)

Comment: Another issue is that there is no pagination button if there is no inbox item on that page.

Comment: @hims056 yeah, that message is AJAX response that actually means "there are no inbox items for page [page here]"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It pains me to remove an "off by one" error, but if I must, I must.

Comment: Thanks! Is this already on production? I still see [same issue here](http://stackexchange.com/users/2545019/ben-12?tab=favorites)... ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290017/page-two-of-favorites-is-a-lie), which I assumed is the same root cause behind those two.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Same bug, two different places. I'm rolling out a fix for the favorites tab as well.

Comment: @AdamLear the same problem is occurring with the All Questions page.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354139/all-questions-page-count-shows-1-extra-empty-page-if-last-page-is-full).