# Page two of Favorites is a lie

Tags: bug, status-completed, bookmarks, stackexchange.com, pagination

I was perusing my [favorite questions list](https://stackexchange.com/users/2545019/ben-12?tab=favorites) in my network profile when I clicked on page 2. I was surprised when I was confronted with an error stating that no favorites were found. The fact that there is a page 2 option leads one to believe that there is in fact a page 2.

Upon further inspection I found that I had exactly 30 favorite questions. This magic number prompts the pagination controls to appear. To see if this was in fact a bug (a minor bug..) I found another question to favorite, and returned to see if page 2 was still a lie. Alas, the 31st favorite appears on the second page.

I then removed two questions from my favorites list (29 total)... The pagination controls are no longer present on my favorites tab.

I propose that the pagination controls should only appear when there are greater than 30 favorites.

This seems to be related/similar to the issue seen here: [Pagination might cause permalinks to open the wrong page, no matter what sorting is used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38103/pagination-might-cause-permalinks-to-open-the-wrong-page-no-matter-what-sorting?rq=1)

Comment: I reported a similar bug over three years ago, it's the in "core" of pagination on stackexchange.com code. (its logic of calculating page count is wrong.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same issue as [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209581/network-profile-inbox-page-count-is-off-by-1-if-last-page-has-exactly-20-items), but in a different part of the code.

The fix is out in production now.