# Bumping locked question to the homepage

Tags: bug, bump, locked-questions, historical-lock

[Locked question](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2775/176217) has been recently bumped to the homepage by Community user. Bumping used to vote for answers, but in the current locked question voting is not possible. Why the question has been bumped?

Comment: Oh...still not fixed for 3 years.

Comment: Yup, like most non-fatal bugs. You can start a bounty, but personally don't think the team will spend time on such a minor bug. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard all of offered by me bounties for questions tagged [tag:bug] have not achived desired effect, i.e. fixing when bounty is in action. So I established in the opinion that bounties for bugs is ineffective.

Comment: Well, I've started over 200, and the ratio is something about 1:20 i.e. one out of 20 bounties will get you the desired effect, you just need patience, and luck. Two recent examples where bounty "worked" for me: [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285049/missing-font-on-some-error-and-dupehammer-info-popups), [two](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209581/network-profile-inbox-page-count-is-off-by-1-if-last-page-has-exactly-20-items).

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think that the bounty is a real motive to fix. Probably only a bumping of the question is enough that developer noticed a bug and knew how to easily fix it.

Comment: True, but when there is nothing to edit or add, the proper way to bump is bounty. :) (I mean that edit like "bump, please fix" is improper.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yep. I recently laugh a lot when read description for the [tag:bump] tag.

Comment: lol, that last sentence was added by me, over three years ago. :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard ha-ha ... You are the omnipresent!