# All Questions page count shows 1 extra empty page if last page is full

Tags: bug, status-declined, question-lists, pagination

This screenshot:
[image]

shows that there are 1871 pages when you click the 1870th page, which has exactly 50 items in it, but the 1871st is empty.  Why is there a 1871st page if it isn't needed?

**EDIT:**

This behavior is only present sometimes.  It took a minute to reproduce this more than three times, because of the number of items coming in and out of the list.

Comment: It probably generates a new page if the last page is full, without checking to see if any would actually be added to that new page.

Comment: Combination of queries done as the state changes & caching. Like most concurrent system specified and/or implemented behaviour.

Comment: Same bug as [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209581/network-profile-inbox-page-count-is-off-by-1-if-last-page-has-exactly-20-items) - it happens only when the last page has the page size amount of items, in your case 50. Now since two more questions were asked after yours, the  bug doesn't "happen", but it's not caching - when there will be 50 exactly in the last page, a "zombie page" will appear and be empty when clicked.

Comment: Maybe there were two  questions on the 1871st page but then the system deleted two questions leaving a blank page.

Comment: @Mari-LouA even so, it shouldn't leave a "zombie" empty page.

Answer (score 3):

As you note, this is an intermittent issue, and I wasn't able to reproduce it.

Additionally, based on our [current roadmap](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/), this isn't work that we will take on, as it doesn't coincide with functional areas that we plan to improve in the near future. We recognize that time and thought was put into this request, but unfortunately, we can't prioritize it at this time.

Comment: I disagree. This can be reproduced when the last page has exactly 50 questions (when page size is 50), then there appears "extra" page which is blank when clicked. I also said that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354139/all-questions-page-count-shows-1-extra-empty-page-if-last-page-is-full#comment1183618_354139). I do accept a decision to reject the bug based on the new canonical "not in our roadmap", but in such case tag should be changed to [tag:status-declined].

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating I implemented a few paginations in C# ASP.NET and this is a lot more difficult than it may seem. If you check Google main page the pagination is often also broken :P

Comment: @bad_coder never said it was easy to fix. Just possible to reproduce. And yeah, got into lots of trouble implementing pagination as well. ;)

Comment: I didn't say it was impossible to reproduce, @ShadowWizardisVaccinating, I said _I_ wasn't able to reproduce it since the issue occurs intermittently... but I guess you disagree with the fact that I wasn't able to reproduce it...? I'll change the tag, if that's the cause for contention here ;)

Comment: @JNat yes, the [tag:status-norepro] tag is "final" and means no further attempts to fix it will be made since it's not possible (for the developers who should fix it) to reproduce the problem. Declined is also final, but fits better here. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating regarding their new stance on status-declined it's no longer final but should be interpreted as "status-declined-for-now"